# Having my bundle in a non-root folder

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm creating a web-site with `react` using `webpack`.

Currently my `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './scripts/main.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'bundle.js'  
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query:{
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then I start the dev server using `webpack-dev-server --progress --colors` and whenever I change a javascript file, my web-page refreshes, and everything seems to be working fine. However, I would like my `bundle.js` file to reside in another folder than the root folder. I therefore changed the line `path: __dirname,` to `path: __dirname + '/dist',`.

Now, when I make a change to the script files, the bundle does not get automatically updated, but if I manually run the `webpack` command it gets built. So my question is: what is the proper way to get my `bundle.js`file to be put in the `dist` folder and still get the `webpack-dev-server` to automatically update when I do a change to my scripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [output.publicPath](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-publicpath) to tell webpack dev server from where to serve your bundled file.

> The Webpack Dev Server also takes a hint from publicPath using it to determine where to serve the output files from.

**webpack.config.js**

```
output: {
  path: __dirname + '/dist',
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  publicPath: '/dist/'
},
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the bundle.js in a different place other than route, i discovered that you can put the entire path in filename.

```
output: {
  path: __dirname + '/public',
  filename: 'static/assets/script/app.bundle.js'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Such configuration for me fine:

```
var path = require('path');

output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: "[name].js"
},
```

Also ensure your webpack config palced in a relative to this path folder.

P.S. also take a look on *browser-sync* instead of dev-server module. As it calls all loaders, etc. and supports hot-modules, etc..

P.S.2. 
From webpack dev server [official page](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html)

```
It will not be written to your configured output directory
```

So I suggest you to use browser-async plugin to get the same functionality.

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/deeptowncitizen/currency-fetcher/)

Comment: I got the exact same problem when I used `path.join`. My webpack.config is located in my project root folder, and dist is a sub-folder to my root folder.